# Authentication Logon page not working using PHP and Oracle on Apache / Windows 2008

Tags: php, apache, authentication, oracle11g, windows-server-2008

[UPDATE: Solved: Thanks everyone. See code here: http://pastebin.com/1fJmXeG2] I greatly appreciate any help I can get on this problem. We have a logon page on our site running on an old Linux server using Apache 1 and PHP 4. We want to move it to a new Windows 2008 server (64-bit)... so I installed Apache 2.25 and PHP 5.4 on the new server. I also enabled OCI8 connecting to an Oracle 11g database. I moved the files for the logon page over to the new server and they don't work. What happens is the page does not run the script and it just forwards to the index.php instead of redirecting to index php with the appropriate response. Of course there was some deprecated language which I updated in the PHP script, but it still doesn't work. I am a complete newbie so I am not sure if it is a problem with the script or a problem with the PHP settings. I know I can connect to the database, since I made a test page doing so. Please help me if you can... I am really desperate. The following is the code for my authorization page:

```
<?php session_start();
// Begin or continue session by registering variables
$_SESSION['USER_ID'] = 'USER_ID';
$_SESSION['PASSWORD'] = 'PASSWORD';
$_SESSION['FIRST'] = 'FIRST';
$_SESSION['LAST'] = 'LAST';
$_SESSION['ACCESS_KEY'] = 'ACCESS_KEY';
$_SESSION['conn'] = 'conn';
$_SESSION['BEENHERE'] = 'BEENHERE';
$_SESSION['CUSTOMER_NAME'] = 'CUSTOMER_NAME';
$_SESSION['WAREHOUSING'] = 'WAREHOUSING';
$_SESSION['TRANSPORTATION'] = 'TRANSPORTATION';
$_SESSION['MYACCOUNT'] = 'MYACCOUNT';

// Set Environment Variables
$SYS_DBUSER = "*****";
$SYS_DBPASSWORD = "*****";
$SYS_DB = "*****";

// Begin Authorization Routine
if ( (!isset($USER_ID)) && (!isset($PASSWORD)) )
    {
    echo '<html>';
    echo '<head>';
    echo '<title> Customer Access - Login</title>';
    echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">';
    echo '</head>';
    echo '<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">';
    echo '<div align="center">';
    echo '<p><img src="../images/logocir3.gif" width="120" height="123"> </p>';
    echo '<p><b><font size="5" color="#0000FF" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">The ';
    echo 'The Company</font></b></p>';
    echo '<p><font size="4" color="#0000FF" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b><i>Customer Access</i></b></font></p>';
    echo '<form name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">';
    echo '<p> <font size="3" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Username:</font> ';
    echo '<input type="text" name="USER_ID" maxlength="15">';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p><font size="3" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Password: </font> ';
    echo '<input type="PASSWORD" name="PASSWORD" maxlength="15">';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></p>';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</body>';
    echo '</html>';
    exit;
    }
elseif ( ($BEENHERE == 1) && (isset($FIRST)) && (isset($PASSWORD)) && (isset($ACCESS_KEY)) && (isset($USER_ID)) && (isset($LAST)) && (isset($conn)) && (isset($CUSTOMER_NAME)) )
    {
    return (TRUE);
    }
else
    {
    // Connect to database
    unset($conn);
    $conn = oci_connect($SYS_DBUSER,$SYS_DBPASSWORD,$SYS_DB);

    // Generate sql statement
    $loginsql = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,CUSTOMER_NAME,ACCESS_KEY,TRANSPORTATION,WAREHOUSING,MYACCOUNT FROM WEB_USERS WHERE USER_ID = SUBSTR(UPPER('$USER_ID'),1,15) AND PASSWORD = SUBSTR(UPPER('$PASSWORD'),1,30) AND ENABLED = 'Y'");

    // Execute statement
    oci_execute($loginsql,OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);

    // Retrieve number of rows for authentication
    $nrows = oci_fetch_all($loginsql,$results);

    // Database Authenticate
    if ( $nrows != 1 )
        {
        // Display if login fails
        unset($USER_ID);
        unset($PASSWORD);
        unset($FIRST);
        unset($LAST);
        unset($ACCESS_KEY);
        unset($conn);
        unset($BEENHERE);
        unset($CUSTOMER_NAME);
        unset($WAREHOUSING);
        unset($TRANSPORTATION);
        unset($MYACCOUNT);
        echo "<H1>Login Failure - Please Check Your Password AND/OR Username</H1><BR>";
        echo "<A HREF=\"$PHP_SELF\"><H3>Try Again</H3></A>";

        // Close used resources
        oci_free_statement($loginsql);
        oci_close($conn);
        exit;
        }
    else
        {
        // Assign login information to global variables
        unset($FIRST);
        unset($LAST);
        unset($ACCESS_KEY);
        unset($BEENHERE);
        unset($CUSTOMER_NAME);
        unset($WAREHOUSING);
        unset($TRANSPORTATION);
        unset($MYACCOUNT);
        $FIRST = $results['FIRST_NAME'][0];
        $LAST = $results['LAST_NAME'][0];
        $CUSTOMER_NAME = $results['CUSTOMER_NAME'][0];
        $ACCESS_KEY = $results['ACCESS_KEY'][0];
        $TRANSPORTATION = $results['TRANSPORTATION'][0];
        $WAREHOUSING = $results['WAREHOUSING'][0];
        $MYACCOUNT = $results['MYACCOUNT'][0];
        $BEENHERE = 1;

        // Close used resources
        oci_free_statement($loginsql);
        oci_close($conn);
        }
    }
        ?>
```

Here are my php settings in a png file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3ziM.png

Comment: I tried installing PHP 4.9 but it seems that the script cannot connect to the database using any version of the Oracle Client on Windows 2008 with that version of PHP. From a security standpoint it is time to upgrade anyway.

Comment: Also when you have a failed logon the old linux server passes a cookie to the temp folder that looks like this:
!USER_ID|!PASSWORD|!FIRST|!;LAST|!ACCESS_KEY|!conn|!BEENHERE|!;CUSTOMER_NAME|!WAREHOUSING|!TRANSPORTATION|!MYACCOUNT|

The new server passes a cookie like this:
USER_ID|s:7:"USER_ID";PASSWORD|s:8:"PASSWORD";FIRST|s:5:"FIRST";LAST|s:4:"LAST";ACCESS_KEY|s:10:"ACCESS_KEY";conn|s:4:"conn";BEENHERE|s:8:"BEENHERE";CUSTOMER_NAME|s:13:"CUSTOMER_NAME";WAREHOUSING|s:11:"WAREHOUSING";TRANSPORTATION|s:14:"TRANSPORTATION";MYACCOUNT|s:9:"MYACCOUNT";

I have no idea what this means if anything.

Comment: The old file connected to the database using the PHP 4 style: putenv('ORACLE_BASE=C:/oclient/product/11.2.0'); putenv('ORACLE_HOME=C:/oclient/product/11.2.0/client_2'); putenv('TNS_ADMIN=C:/oclient/product/11.2.0/client_2/NETWORK/ADMIN/tnsnames.ora'‌​); putenv('TWO_TASK=C:/oclient/product/11.2.0/client_2/NETWORK/ADMIN/tnsnames.ora')‌​; putenv('ORA_NLS33=C:/oclient/product/11.2.0/client_2/nls/data'); putenv('ORACLE_SID=PROD'); $SYS_DBUSER = "*****"; $SYS_DBPASSWORD = "*****"; $SYS_DB = "*****"

Comment: Thanks everyone. I found out that the code needed to be rewritten completely. Jeffwa pointed me in the right direction. Here is the correct code that works. Thanks everyone! http://pastebin.com/1fJmXeG2

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the rest, but you need to add session_start(); to the top of your php page. This should be the first thing on every page you carry your sessions on. I usually put it right next to the tag like so:

```
<?php session_start();
...
```

Comment: Did that... still no luck. Thanks though.

Comment: Hey... it still doesn't work but the cookies are being added to the temp file. THANKS... one more issue delt with.

Answer (score 2):

Since PHP4, request variables are only available via the arrays $_GET (for GET requests) and $_POST (for POST requests). You've got some rewriting to do, starting off with turning

```
if ( (!isset($USER_ID)) && (!isset($PASSWORD)) )
```

into

```
if ( (!isset($_POST)) )
```

or

```
if ( (!array_key_exists('USERID', $_POST)) && (!array_key_exists('PASSWORD', $_POST)) )
```

More:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php

Answer (score 1):

Lots of things to fix in your code:

1. Like joemurphy said, to check if the form has been submitted:

   ```
   if (!isset($_POST)) {....}
   ```
2. Don't use lots of `echo` statements to display HTML. Close your PHP tag (`?>`) and just output the HTML code as normal. Then when you're finished with the HTML, add a PHP opening tag (`<php`) and continue with your PHP code.
3. Check for values in `$_SESSION` with

   ```
   if (isset($_SESSION['USER_ID'])){...}
   ```

   If you need a specific value:

   ```
   if (isset($_SESSION['USER_ID']) && $_SESSION['USER_ID'] == 1){...}
   ```
4. You don't need to set dummy values to initialize them in session or unset them before setting them. Set them only when you have appropriate values for them, then clear them out on logout. So delete the "Begin or continue session by registering variables" section.